# Permissão Usuário SQl Server

Tags: sql-server

Preciso criar um usuário dentro do login Sql Server com acesso as databases, porém não quero liberar nenhum outro recurso (como Security, server role, Sql Agent, backup e etc). Esse usuário é para o desenvolvimento de sistemas, existe algum usuário padrão para essa finalidade??

Answer (score 2):

Você cria o usuário e no Server Roles você seta as permissões.
É possível também mapear o usuário diretamente para um DB no menu User Mapping.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Detalhes sobre as Server Roles:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles

Comment: Sim, essa opção eu conheço. Porém quando libero, o usuário fica mostrando outras opções do SSMS, tais como:  Security, server role, Sql Agent, backup. Tem alguma opção para que não apareça para usuário desenvolvedor?? Só queria liberar as DB (tabelas, procedures e views).

Comment: @MMoura ele vê as opções mas não pode fazer nada